# including a javascript file in a JS file without using <script>

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of JS which more or less looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.script.com/jsapi">
    player = new playrer.Player('Yplayer',{
    styleid: '0',
    client_id: 'YOUR YOUKUOPENAPI CLIENT_ID',
    vid: 'Replace the Youku Video ID'
});
</script>
```

Which would work if I directly drop it into my html document via script tag. But I am trying to call this by including a separate global javascript file. Can I avoid including the remote .jsapi via the `<script>`

Comment: You can't have both an `src=` attribute AND a script body..

Comment: what's he trying to do is just including a file js which contains the script body.

Comment: [John Resig: Degrading Script Tags](http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/)

Answer (score 2):

a solution will be using jquery **[getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)** function

```
$.getScript( "http://player.script.com/jsapi", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  player = new playrer.Player('Yplayer',{
        styleid: '0',
        client_id: 'YOUR YOUKUOPENAPI CLIENT_ID',
        vid: 'Replace the Youku Video ID'
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use both the `src` attribute and javascript code (body content) inside the same  tag.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, the "jsapi" script will execute, but ignore your local javaScript. You need:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.script.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
player = new playrer.Player('Yplayer',{
  styleid: '0',
  client_id: 'YOUR YOUKUOPENAPI CLIENT_ID',
  vid: 'Replace the Youku Video ID'
});
</script>
```

You can put the embedded script in another file if you wish